# Why was my open-source ad deleted?

Tags: support, open-source-advertising

I'm a FreeBSD/OpenBSD/NetBSD/DragonFly developer, and I run an OpenGrok service for the use and cross reference of other UNIX developers and users; [today is it's 1-year anniversary](http://www.freebsd.org/news/status/report-2013-01-2013-03.html#BXR.SU-%E2%80%94-Super-User%27s-BSD-Cross-Reference), only for me to find out that an ad for it on SO was abruptly deleted a couple of days ago (on Mar 29), after gaining support and being featured for a while.

Why was the ad deleted?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211381/221016

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the other ads. Most lead directly to the GitHub project page where those who want to contribute can join.

Looks like you missed the Ad Requirements:

> It must be an advertisement **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).

Your ad leads to some kind of a form, hence not following the above requirements.

I remember it used to lead elsewhere in the past, since the link wasn't changed it means its target site changed. If you have a page describing how to contribute, link to it instead and flag your answer asking to undelete.

Comment: As well, the image *itself* does not mention anything that solicits participation or contribution. I deleted quite a few of them because we've really been veering away from the guidelines and a lot of them that have been popping up are just straight-up advertisements that don't follow said guidelines.

Comment: I've now changed it to link to a search for `todo`, `XXX` and `fixme`, but I cannot undelete -- i'm getting a message that it was deleted by a moderator and cannot be undeleted

Comment: @cnst Could you modify the image somehow to indicate that you expect people to **contribute**? The link is only part of the problem.

Comment: @animuson, I've updated the image, too, now.

Comment: @cnst looks better and while I have no idea what this is all about technically, looks like it's fine now. animuson will hopefully undelete when he'll see your latest reply.

Comment: Thank you for restoring it.

Comment: Not my doing @cnst, but glad I could guide in the right direction.